# How do i paginate long articles from the client side using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I am trying to come up with a way to paginate an article smoothly from the client side using Jquery or Javascript so that long articles can be viewed as multiple pages.

I need it to split the content based on page size and even break sentences and divs into different pages(if need be).

I need it to be able to handle iframes, images, list items, tables and videos as well

I really hope someone can help me soon, as i have been trying for months to try to fix this situation.

If anyone needs more clarification, please do ask

Thanks

Comment: Just my 2cents: don't do it, paginating by the size of rendered content is a headache and full of gremlins - e.g. late-loading content/waiting and then resizing, window resizing etc - why do you want to annoy the user by hiding content from them if it's already available?

Comment: go through this link http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

Comment: This question shouldn't be posted without code you've tried. Also using JavaScript to paginate an article might not be a good idea for lots of reasons!

Comment: Ive used a plugin called textpager and even a plugin called textify
But both seemed to fail my cause

 $('#longText2')
                        .textify({
                        numberOfColumn: 1,
                        margin: 20,
                        padding: 15,
                        width: "auto",
                        height: "auto",
                        showNavigation: true,
                        textAlign: 'justify'
                    })

Comment: @AJS  But the issue is i am trying to paginate text and not lists or table of contents

Comment: Just don't. CSS3 can be used to break sentences so no need for js. And pagination is used to reduce server stress and allow people to share a permalink for olderposts and many other reasons!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do that using **Ajax**.

A very simplified way of doing this would be:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="loadmore">Load More!</button>
```

**jQuery / Ajax**:

```
var i = 1;
$("#loadmore").click(function(){ // on load more button click
    $.ajax({
        url: "datagrab.php", // get data from backend
        method: "post",
        data: {section: i} // which section to grab data from (ie: 1 = the first 200 characters; 2 = from the 200th character to the 400th e.t.c...)
        success: function(data){
            $("#container").append(data); // append data to #container
            i++;
        }, 
        error: function(){
            alert("There was a problem!");
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously, this is a **very** basic approach to it, however, based on the "information" you gave me, this is all I can really provide..

If you want to find out more about how to do this, have a look at some **YouTube** videos about pagination with **Ajax**.

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention, I am doing this for VisualForce, so I cannot use PHP else i would have tried that

Comment: @JubinJames same sort of approach mate. Just gotta change a couple of values. I only used **PHP** because it's what the majority of people use.